# maven COMPILATION ERROR : package could not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

hello i am trying to develop a project with spring. There are multiple modules in my project. I am using amqp module in borrow-service. For this, I added my amqp to the pom file of borrow-service and I can use amqp module in borrow-service without any problems. But when I trying to do mvn clean install in borrow-service maven build failures. What's the problem? Thanks.

amqp pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.ky</groupId>
<artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>amqp</name>
<description>amqp</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    ...
            </dependencies>
```

borrow-service pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.ky</groupId>
<artifactId>borrow-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>borrow-service</name>
<description>borrow-service</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ky</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
    </dependencies>
```

I am trying to do build my borrow-service using mvn clean install however, i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] package com.ky.amqp.dto does not exist
[ERROR] package com.ky.amqp.producer does not exist
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RabbitMQMessageProducer
  location: class com.ky.borrowservice.service.BorrowService
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RabbitMQMessageProducer
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RabbitMQMessageProducer
[ERROR]   location: class com.ky.borrowservice.service.BorrowService
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RabbitMQMessageProducer
[ERROR]   location: class com.ky.borrowservice.service.BorrowService
[ERROR] package com.ky.amqp.dto does not exist
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class BorrowBookRequest
[ERROR]   location: class com.ky.borrowservice.controller.BorrowController
[ERROR]  cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class BorrowBookRequest
[ERROR]   location: class com.ky.borrowservice.controller.BorrowController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: please don't add (links to) images, just post the relevant information as formatted text in your question

Comment: Let me guess both project include the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @M.Deinum they are :), solved now thank you so much. However, i wonder what's its logic? Why it gave the error? Can you please explain in short?

Comment: The Spring Boot Maven plugin creates a special fatjar which isn't usable as a dependency. The Spring Boot Maven plugin should only be a part of the project that contains the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.